# "Error unprotecting the session cookie" in ASP.NET Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, cookies, .net-6.0

I have a web application running in production since the end of 2021. It had been running on ASP.NET Core 5.0 in an Azure App Service (linux) container. The system contains a custom OpenID Connect server made with Duende Identity Server nuget package, so the session cookie of the application contains authentication info.

Everything went fine, but two weeks ago I migrated the project from net5 to net6, and exceptions like below are being thrown since then:

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware[7]
Error unprotecting the session cookie.
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The payload was invalid. For more information go to http://aka.ms/dataprotectionwarning
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Managed.ManagedAuthenticatedEncryptor.Decrypt(ArraySegment`1 protectedPayload, ArraySegment`1 additionalAuthenticatedData)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.CookieProtection.Unprotect(IDataProtector protector, String protectedText, ILogger logger)
```

For the first time, I thought that the old data protection keys are missing from the key ring, but I found all the protection keys generated since the first deploy (they are persisted to the file system). This is the most recent one:

```
<key id="xy" version="1">
<creationDate>2023-03-02T02:31:35.2845259Z</creationDate>
<activationDate>2023-03-03T16:46:59.1304486Z</activationDate>
<expirationDate>2023-05-31T02:31:34.7095525Z</expirationDate>
<descriptor deserializerType="Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AuthenticatedEncryption.ConfigurationModel.AuthenticatedEncryptorDescriptorDeserializer, Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60">
<descriptor>
<encryption algorithm="AES_256_CBC"/>
<validation algorithm="HMACSHA256"/>
<masterKey xmlns:p4="http://schemas.asp.net/2015/03/dataProtection" p4:requiresEncryption="true">
<!--  Warning: the key below is in an unencrypted form.  -->
<value>xy</value>
</masterKey>
</descriptor>
</descriptor>
</key>
```

Then I thought that the problem should be the deserializerType attribute in the xml above, which references a net5 assembly, while the project is now running on net6. But I don't guess that this should cause a problem (why whould it anyway), and the next interesting fact is that:

> This only happens to some users. I logged in and out from the system, thus creating and destroying session cookies, and I cannot reproduce the "error unprotecting the session cookie" exception.

I guess that some users may have old session cookies, but all data protection keys are being present, so I'm not sure if old session cookies would lead to these exceptions (but I'm really not sure).

**How can I solve this problem?**

This is the authentication configuration (I changed all sensitive data in it):

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
    .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Domain = "xy.com";
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        options.Cookie.Name = "xy_cookie";
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        //...
    });
```

Comment: Applications may not save cookies when old, stale cookies are present. Have you tried clearing cookies?

Comment: @Chen Tried multiple times, also tried renaming all cookies in configuration. No stale cookies are present (checked by logging), but the error remains.